# Multiple ablines in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot two ablines in R, but conditional upon a certain value. The graph I wish to plot has a slope of -1 and intercept y=50, up until the value 50. It then has a slope of 0 and intercept 0 after that for all x.

The code:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
abline(a=50,b=-1)
##abline(a=0,b=0)
axis(1)
axis(2)
title(main="Graph")
title(xlab="X")
title(ylab="Y")
box()
```

Using the normal abline I am able to get one or the other, but I'm unsure how to add both in the same graph without any overlap. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of line you can use function `lines()` and then provide start and end values for x values (0 and 50) and for y values use linear regression equation as `a+b*x` where `a=50` and `b=-1` and for x  use the same values. Second part can be made also with function `segments()` where you put your coordinates for start and end. First line also can be made with `segments()` if you already now starting and end points for that line.

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
lines(x=c(0,50),y=50-1*c(0,50))
segments(50,0,100,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want a line that goes from x=0 to x=50 with an intercept of y=50 and with a slope of -1, and then from x=50 to x=100 with a slope of 0. You could use lines() instead of abline() for this.

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
lines(c(0,50,100), c(50,0,0))
axis(1)
axis(2)
title(main="Graph")
title(xlab="X")
title(ylab="Y")
box()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the function `segments` who `Draw line segments between pairs of points.`

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
#abline(a=50,b=-1)
#abline(a=0,b=0)
segments(0,50,50,0)
segments(50,0,100,0)
axis(1)
axis(2)
title(main="Graph")
title(xlab="X")
title(ylab="Y")
box()
```

Here is how the plot looks like: [image]

Comment: Thanks B.Mr.W, is it possible also to make the plot so that the graph actually crosses the x and y-axis? Apologies, I'm still pretty new to graphics in R.

Comment: @ClattyCake an easy-solution would be tweak the points a bit so that the line cross the axis. like `segments(-50,100,50,0) 
segments(50,0,150,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `ablineclip` from plotrix:

```
plot(1, type='n', xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100),
   xlab="X", ylab="Y")
library(plotrix)
ablineclip(50,-1, x1=0, x2=50)
ablineclip(0,0,x1=50, x2=100)
```